# Available height to position UI elements assuming keyboard always shows

Tags: swift

I am encountering a problem that I'm not sure how to solve.  If you look at the screenshot below, you'll see that the UI is laid out so that it neatly fits into the space between the safe area layout guide's top anchor and the top of the keyboard.

The keyboard will ALWAYS be shown in this view controller.  But I need a way of knowing what the height of the keyboard is so that I can do some math to figure out how to tall to make the UITextView (the red box).

I tried the approach of registering for notifications on when the keyboard will show, but that is too late.

I need a way of knowing the height of the keyboard before the view renders so that I can configure the height of each of the elements in the UI.

Is there a way to do this?

Thank you!

[image: Screenshot of View Controller]

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to capture the dimensions of the Keyboard when it IS presented then pass those dimensions into this view.

However, you will also want to make sure that you are handling cases such as the split keyboard on an iPad and things of that nature.

For that you might choose to look at the documentation on using the `keyboardLayoutGuide` and use it with some constraints.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/keyboards_and_input/adjusting_your_layout_with_keyboard_layout_guide